# Predict with tensorflow lite input_data from CountVectorizer: ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type STRING but expected type FLOAT32

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I saved a Keras CNN with TFLiteConverter and also the CountVectorizer (scikit-learn) that was used during training of the same model using pickle.

When I load both and try to predict the result of a new example I occur following error:

`ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type STRING but expected type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: serving_default_input_2:0`

See the code below:

```
    loaded_vectorizer = pickle.load(open("models/vectorizer.pickle", 'rb'))
    input_data = loaded_vectorizer.transform([html])

    # Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
    interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path='models/model.tflite')
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    # Get input and output tensors.
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

    # Test the model on input data.
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

    interpreter.invoke()

    # The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
    # Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

The error occurs in this line:

`interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)`

I have no clue why, tested several casting options. I also checked, whether the vectorizer output is of the same type than in the trained model (`<1x123418 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>' with 853 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`). But I can also cast it to float32... it does not change the error...

Help is highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it running...

I just had to make the `input_data` an array:

```
input_data = loaded_vectorizer.transform([html]).astype('float32')
input_data = input_data.toarray()
```